# How to add 2 elements from 2 different JTextField to one JList

Tags: java

How can I add elements from different JTextFields to one List. I've tried to put the elements in Strings and add them to the list but thats not working.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide more details as to what exactly you are doing and elaborate "not working". There is not much information to help you in this current form.

Comment: How exactly did you add the strings to the list? Are you aware that they must be added to the list's model? So you can create a `DefaultListModel`, add all initial elements to that model and create the `JList` from this model. Then you can add new elements to the `DefaultListModel` instance and they should appear in your `JList`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the strings to the list model that backs up the `JList`. Here is short example code that appends the current `JTextField`'s value to the list whenever you hit ENTER in the text field:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public final class Example extends JFrame {
   public Example() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // Create a list model and populate it with two initial items.
      final DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
      model.addElement("Initial 1");
      model.addElement("Initial 2");

      // Create a JList (wrapped into a JScrollPane) from the model
      add(new JScrollPane(new JList<String>(model)), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      // Create a JTextField at the top of the frame.
      // Whenever you click ENTER in that field, the current string gets
      // appended to the list model and will thus show up in the JList.
      final JTextField field1 = new JTextField("Field 1");
      add(field1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Append " + field1.getText());
               model.addElement(field1.getText());
            }
         });

      // Create a JTextField at the bottom of the frame.
      // Whenever you click ENTER in that field, the current string gets
      // appended to the list model and will thus show up in the JList.
      final JTextField field2 = new JTextField("Field 2");
      add(field2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      field2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Append " + field2.getText());
               model.addElement(field2.getText());
            }
         });
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JFrame frame = new Example();
      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(1); }
         });
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```